How to show $y- ke^{y-1}$ must have two zeros?
Assume
$$
y=cv(x)+1,~~~ u=\frac{rx}{c}
$$
where $r,c$ are constants. If $v(x)$ is bounded, then how to show
$$
\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm du} = y- ke^{y-1}
$$
must have two zeros?
The problem is from the red lines of the excerpt below.

which can be integrated again to
$$
v' = \frac{r}{c} v + \frac{r}{c^2} \Bigg[ 1 - ke^{cv} \Bigg] \tag{10.5}
$$
with $\color{red}{\underline{\color{black}{\text{an arbitrary constant} \, k}}}$. Now if we substitute $\color{red}{\underline{\color{black}{y = cv + 1 \, \text{and} \, u = rx/c}}}$ we get the equation
$$
\color{red}{\underline{\color{black}{\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm du} = y - ke^{y-1}}}}
$$
whose solutions are given by
$$
u = \int \frac{\mathrm dy}{y - ke^{y-1}}. \tag{10.6}
$$
Now suppose we have a solution $g(x)$ where as $x \to -\infty$ we have an expansion
$$
g(x) = b \, e^{\lambda x} + c \, e^{2\lambda x} + \ldots
$$
in powers of $e^{\lambda x}$ with no constant term. Then $v(x)$ will have an expansion
$$
v(x) = a + \lambda b \, e^{\lambda x} + 2\lambda c \, e^{\lambda x} + \ldots
$$
and hence be bounded as $x \to -\infty$. Likewise if $g(x)$ has an expansion
$$
g(x) = b \, e^{-\mu x} + c \, e^{-\mu x} + \ldots
$$
as $x \to +\infty$ then $v(x)$ will be
$$
v(x) = a - b \mu \, e^{-\mu x} - 2c \mu \, e^{-2\mu x} - \ldots
$$
and hence will also be bounded as $x \to +\infty$. $\color{red}{\underline{\color{black}{\text{If $v$ is bounded so is $y$, while $u \to \pm \infty$ when $x$ does. Therefore the denominator}}}}$  $\color{red}{\underline{\color{black}{\text{in the previous integral must have two zeros}}}}$. This happens precisely when $0 < k < 1$.



Analyze asymptotic behavior:

Find the derivative:


$$f'(y) = 1 - k e^{y - 1}$$

Set  to find critical points:

$$1 = k e^{y - 1}$$
$$y = 1 - \ln(k)$$

Check concavity using the second derivative:

$$f''(y) = -k e^{y - 1}$$

Apply the Intermediate Value Theorem:

Since there is a local maximum at both and, the function must cross the x-axis twice, meaning there are two zeros.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

A local maximum don't means that the function must corss the x-axis twice. For example, $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$.

Consider instead
$$k(y)=y\,e^{1-y}\quad \implies \quad k'(y)=(1-y)\,e^{1-y}$$ So, the derivative cancels for $y=1$ and the second derivative test shows that this is a maximum. Since $k(1)=1$ and you look for $0 < k<1$ there are two solutions in $y$.
In fact, the solutions $y_1$ and $y_2$ are explicitely given in terms of Lambert function.
